# Rewrite url using htaccess with parameter

Tags: .htaccess

My original url is : test.com/a/b/index.php/index/sub?query1=1&query2=2.

I want to rewrite it to : test.com/a/b/cate/1/2.

I'm using htaccess with these lines :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /a/b
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^cate/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php/index/sub?query1=$1&query2=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

It doesn't work. I don't know why.
Can someone help ?

Edit: I'm using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Actually i'm using CodeIgniter. I think problem is from the config uri_protocol , REQUEST_URL or QUERY_STRING ...

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean? When I use this snippet in my test environment, it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I edited this varriable in file config : $config['uri_protocol'] to PATH_INFO and it works now. I know it weird but it doesn't work if default value is REQUEST_URI.